# Token Comma expected - can not run JSON query

Tags: excel, powerquery, json-query

This is a problem i have working in Excels Power Query.
I have this query saved in a variable named "content" which is passed to the call Web.Contents.

I  can not run the query, i get "Token Comma expected" error. Can somebody tell what that is about?

```
`let
content = "{
"query": [
    {
      "code": "Region",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "vs:RegionKommun07",
        "values": [
          "1283"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Sysselsattning",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "FÖRV"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Alder",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "30-34"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Kon",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Tid",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "2015"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "px"
  }
}",
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/AM/AM0207/AM0207H/BefSyssAldKonK", [Content=Text.ToBinary(content)]))
in
    Source`
```

Comment: do you have the line where the error comes from? also could you try deleting the coma before line `Source = Json...`

Comment: Yes, it is pointing to line 3 "query"

Comment: have you tried deleting the comma?

Comment: Deleting the comma before line Source didn't help

Comment: If you want `"` inside a quoted string then you need to double them up like `""` to escape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `"` inside a quoted string then you need to double them up like `""` to escape them.

```
let
content = "{
""query"": [
    {
      ""code"": ""Region"",
      ""selection"": {
        ""filter"": ""vs:RegionKommun07"",
        ""values"": [
          ""1283""
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
    ...
    }"
```

See page 21 here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/A/81A62C9B-04D5-4B6D-B162-D28E4D848552/Power%20Query%20M%20Formula%20Language%20Specification%20(July%202019).pdf

> To include quotes in a text value, the quote mark is repeated, as
>   follows: "The ""quoted"" text" // The "quoted" text

Comment: It works with repeated quotes. Thank you very much Tim :)